# Connect and Disconnect Range in Android Bluetooth Programming

Tags: android, sockets, bluetooth, connection, range

I wrote code about android bluetooth programming.I'm connecting to HC06 modules.I used socket and I used Runnable method.If connection has ended I close socket

When I disconnect the bluetooth cable I can see the message of connection failure.But I exit from bluetooth connection range I cannot see the message of connection failure.

I cannot exit from bluetooth device connection range.Even if I move away.

What  must I do?

Answer (score 0):

Use intent filters to listen to the ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED, ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECT_REQUESTED, and ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED broadcasts:

```
public void onCreate() {
    ...
    IntentFilter filter1 = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED);
    IntentFilter filter2 = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECT_REQUESTED);
    IntentFilter filter3 = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED);
    this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter1);
    this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter2);
    this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter3);
}

//The BroadcastReceiver that listens for bluetooth broadcasts
private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
           ... //Device found
        }
        else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED.equals(action)) {
           ... //Device is now connected
        }
        else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)) {
           ... //Done searching
        }
        else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECT_REQUESTED.equals(action)) {
           ... //Device is about to disconnect
        }
        else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED.equals(action)) {
           ... //Device has disconnected
        }           
    }
};
```